# Unreal Engine 4.23 screen flicker

Tags: unreal-engine4, flicker

I have started to use Unreal Engine for hobby and learn c++. The problem is that the screen begins to flicker in UE while i'm works. If I run other programs or applications the screen don't flicker, only flickers in UE. 
I updated the Intel drivers and Nvidia drivers (1050Ti) but the problem is still unsolved.
Thx.

Comment: Sounds like a gpu issue, are you able to play any resource intensive games? It might be the other applications you're using are using an intel integrated chip.

Comment: @George I play normaly to games like Assassins Creed and the GPU works correctly.

Comment: (If you're on windows) I'd probably try going to device manager->Display Adapters and disabling your primary gpu. If the problem persists then that entirely rules out the gpu. However if the problem goes away then try re-enabling, it might just work. If not then my only other suggestion would be to reinstall windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to manage your graphic card in the NVIDIA Control Panel ?
I think that customize your settings for Unreal Engine can fix the problem, I had the same issue and it's working for me.

I don't even know why, but Unreal encounters some issues when he has to deal with different graphics cards in a same time.
So, you have to set manually the graphic card for use in order to avoid conflict and flickering.

- Open your NVIDIA Control Panel
- In the panel Manage 3D Setting, choose Program Setting.
- In the part Select a program to customize : search for Unreal Engine editor(UE4Editor).
- In the part Select the preferred graphic processor.....: choose High-Performance NVIDIA Processor
- Click on apply, & that's all. Reopen Unreal Engine and see if it's working.

Here a screenshot of the settings that you should have.

[Settings in Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjkgk.png)

Comment: Many thx for the answer, but the issue has not been fixed. I have observed that the program works properly when I only works with UE, if I'm in UE and go to Visual Studio (e.g) for programming something or go to browser to search anything, when I return to UE the program flickers.

Comment: I also want to add, you can make UE4 the Priority 1 application for your Card in the same settings as @Ydnic_Wolver explained. It could help the situation from when you focus from one program and back again.

Answer (score 2):

Turning off anti-aliasing worked for me.

[Setting AA off per Mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbBto.jpg)

[General Switch for project : Edit > Project Settings > Engine - Rendering : 
Anti-aliasing mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjyD9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have been having the same issue for the past month now and I have just recently fixed it. The way I did mine was I went under my Nvidia control panel and reset to defaults for the UE4Editor under program settings in 'Manage 3D Settings'. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What solved this issue for me was unchecking Enable Window Animations under the Editor Preferences Window. Edit -> Editor Preferences -> User Interface

[image: Editor Preferences Window]

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats right adding the program to run on nvidia high performance in the nvidia control panel solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have flicker on a Mac (Apple Silicon) in UE 4.27.2 on a second monitor, the main MacBook screen was fine. I had to turn off "Enable High DPI Support" in Preferences->General->Appearance->User Interface.

UE 5.1 doesn't have the same problem.